# DJango - JS - Ajax - Upload file to NRM/Nexus (another domain) - CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, file-upload, cors

PLEASE HELP

With the following JS function

```
`function nexusUploader(file) {
    let filename = file.name,
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('package', file);

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://<external domain (NRM/NEXUS)>",
        type: "PUT",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        cors: false ,
        crossDomain: true,
        secure: true,
        processData: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        headers: {
          'X-CSRFTOKEN': $.cookie("csrftoken"),
          "Authorization": "Basic <KEY>"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}`
```

I am getting the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
global.js:37 09/28/2023 22:06:20:  {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
jquery-3.7.0.min.js:2     PUT https:// net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)